# Casting int[] to object[]

Tags: c#, clr

I encountered with question: why it's impossible cast `int[]` to `object[]` , e.g. 
`object[] o = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };`

Meanwhile I can cast to just `object` and back to `int[]`.

I'll be glad to hear deep answer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx Take a read!

Comment: Side comment, unrelated: don't "cast" stuff. Use the proper data types for the proper data.

Answer (score 10):

Directly from [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa664572(v=vs.98)):

> Array covariance specifically does not extend to arrays of value-types. For example, no conversion exists that permits an int[] to be treated as an object[].

An array of ints or any other value-type is *not* an array of objects. Value types have different storage characteristics to those of reference types. An array of (reference type) objects holds a list of object *references* (with the objects themselves living in the heap), so the slots will always be a constant width. Value types, on the other hand, store their value *directly in the array*, so the slots might be any width. This makes a conversion between the two meaningless.

It's a little confusing because even though value-types are derived from System.Object, they behave very differently to reference types, and object-like behaviour of value types (e.g. boxing) is only possible through magical handling of them by the compiler and runtime, and it doesn't extend to arrays.

As a side note, casting arrays is a well dodgy practice. I wouldn't do it.

Comment: It's ideological question. I've never used code like this. A guy asked me and I couldn't answer.
Can we box values to heap from stack, then take reference and save to object[]? As I think yes. So why you say casting like this is meaningless?

Comment: Because value types and reference types are completely different and the derivation of value types from System.Object is essentially a fraud that falls apart when applied to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

For an instance of type `A` to be *castable* to type `B`, one of the following conditions must be true:

1. there is an [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)/[explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) conversion from `A` to `B`;
2. there is a hierarchical relationship. Such a relationship could be achieve through one of two ways:

   1. deriving `A` from `B` (e.g., `class A : B {}`)
   2. covariance/contravariance. C# allows covariance for:

      1. arrays of reference types (`string[]` > `object[]`) **(*)**
      2. generic types arguments in interfaces/delegates (`IEnumerable<string>` > `IEnumerable<object>` and `Func<string>` > `Func<object>`)
      3. delegates ( `string Method() {}` can be assigned to `delegate object Del();` )

You cannot cast `int[]` to `object[]` because none of the above conditions are true.

---

**(*)** - You should avoid this though - array covariance is broken and was [it was added simply so that the CLR would support Java-like languages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).

Comment: There's no hierarchical relationship between `string[]` and `object[]`, yet `object[] o = new string[] { "0", "1", "2" }` works. As *spender* points out, the issue is that `int` is a value type.

Comment: @p.s.w.g That would be a good explanation if the OP expected `int[]` to be compatible with `object[]` *because* `string[]` is compatible with `object[]`. If that were the case, then explaining the difference between the two cases would be relevant. But I don't think the actual reason that got him confused was the fact that array types are covariant, I don't think he was even aware of that. Bringing array covariance, a "broken" feature and an exceptional case, into the conversation is unnecessary, in my honest opinion. I think your answer (which you deleted) was a much better one.

Comment: @p.s.w.g In other words, I think the reason that drove him to ask the question, was the same reason that would drive him to ask why can't a `List<int>` be casted to `List<object>`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I agree that that's likely the source of confusion. However, the statement about the hierarchical relationship is irrelevant, too, and could just lead to more confusion since *some* arrays can be converted despite the fact that no hierarchical relationship exists. The key reason why OP's code doesn't work is the fact that `int` is a value type (if OP was using `string[]`, he/she might never have noticed this). I didn't downvote, but if this answer were updated to be more clear about what the exact issue is, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I added a note regarding this, just to make it more complete. But now I'm thinking... Is "hierarchical relationship" really irrelevant? There *is* a hierarchical relationship between `string[]` and `object[]` - that's the definition of covariance. Just the same way there is a hierarchical relationship between `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g The more I think about this, the more I think my first answer was right. Hierarchical relationships can be achieved through one of two ways: by directly deriving from a type (e.g., `A: B`), or by means of covariance/contravariance. Neither applies to `int[]` and `object[]`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Updated again, I think it should be crystal clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Although type `System.Int32` derives from object, and references to `System.Int32` object instances can be used as references to `System.Object`, an array of type `System.Int32[]` does not hold instances of `System.Int32`, nor does it hold references to them.  Instead, each element of an array will hold just the 32-bit numeric value associated with an `Int32`, without holding any of the other information associated with an object instance.  Although C# will allow code like:

```
Object[] array = new Object[3];
int five = 5;
array[0] = five;
array[1] = five;
array[2] = array[0];
```

the code isn't storing `five`, nor a reference to it, into the array.  Instead, the assignment to `array[0]` will create a new object of type `System.Int32` which holds the number 5 and store a reference to that.  The assignment to `array[1]` will then create *another* new object of type `System.Int32`, which also holds the value 5, and store a reference to that.  The third assignment will store into `array[2]` a reference to *the same object* as `array[0]`.  Note that even though all three array slots seem to hold the number 5, they actually hold more information than that.  The array also encapsulates the fact that `array[0]` and `array[2]` hold references to one object, while `array[1]` holds a reference to another.

When a reference type is cast to its parent type, the resulting reference is required to identify the same object as the original.  Consequently, the object identified by the resulting reference cannot encapsulate any more information than the object identified by the original (it's the *same object*, after all!).  Because an `Object[]`, even one whose elements all identify instances of `System.Int32`, encapsulates information beyond what can be stored in an `int[]`, it is not possible for an `int[]` and an `Object[]` to be one and the same object.