# int[] using "wrong" Console.WriteLine overload

Tags: c#, arrays

I was working with a coworker on some basic C# tutorials and we came across what we though was an interesting conundrum.

The following code works as expected:

```
string[] strings = { "1", "2", "3" };
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", strings);
```

It gets the string array and prints out the string "1, 2, 3" to the console using the `Console.WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg)` overload of the `WriteLine` method.

However the following code doesn't work:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", ints);
```

You get a `FormatException` with the message `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.` Using Intellisense I can see that it is trying to use the `Console.WriteLine(string format, object arg0)` overload and that is why we are getting that message, it doesn't see `ints` as an array although it obviously is.

If we switch to the more obvious:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", ints[0], ints[1], ints[2]);
```

It works again and uses the `params object[]` overload again.

Is there a reason it does not see the `int[]` as an array for the method? Does the fact that `Int32` is a struct make a difference? If so, why?

**EDIT**

I did a quick test with doubles in the same format and those didn't work as well, which makes me think that it really is the fact the type is a struct but I still do not understand why that would make a difference.

Comment: There is implicit conversion `string[]` -> `object[]`. There is no such conversion for `int[]` -> `object[]`. And yes, it is because `int` is value-type.

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting int\[\] to object\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211476/casting-int-to-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this works with `string` objects is [*Array Covariance*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx) feature of C#.

> For any two reference-types `A` and `B`, if an implicit or explicit reference conversion exists from `A` to `B`, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type `A[]` to the array type `B[]`

There is an implicit conversion from `string` to `object`, so `WriteLine` takes your `string[]` array in place of `object[]` array.

There is no covariance for `int[]`, because `int` is *not* a reference type. If you would like to use an explicit conversion, you can do it like this:

```
object[] ints = (new int[]{ 1,2,3 }).Cast<object>().ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", ints);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/VVkGjg)

Comment: Or just `object[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };`

Comment: @PatrykSpytkowski Well, the idea was to demonstrate how you start with an array of primitives, and end up with an array of `objects`, but yes, your syntax is definitely more concise.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is because `int` is a value-type.  It's trying to find the best match.  `string[]` is convertible to `object[]`, but `int[]` is not because arrays of structs are not covariant.  As a workaround, you could use

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", ints.Cast<Object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: More precisely, `int[]` is an array type (array types are reference types) whose element type `int` is a value type, and array covariance will not work when the element type is a value type, so `int[]` is not convertible into `object[]`.